# MySQL FULLTEXT returning only best answer

Tags: mysql, subquery, full-text-search, hierarchical-data, hierarchical-query

I'm trying to modify the code for fullpath retrieval from this post:
http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/ in nested-set model to use FULLTEXT instead of exact match.

Here's what I want: I want to obtain best match for searched from MATCH() AGAINST() and than use '=' sign to find only this one result.

Here's what I've tried:

```
DELIMITER //
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS find_node;
//

CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER PROCEDURE find_node (
        IN searched TEXT
)

proc: BEGIN

    SELECT DISTINCT parent.content
    FROM tree AS node,
             tree AS parent
    WHERE node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt
    AND node.content = (SELECT content FROM tree WHERE MATCH(node.content) AGAINST(searched IN BOOLEAN MODE) LIMIT 1)
    ORDER BY parent.lft;

END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Line beggining with AND node.content, but it seems that it's not returning any results after running the procedure.
I would like to be able to obtain second, third and n best match as well (maybe using LIMIT 1 OFFSET n, where n is a result number?).

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

This isn't logically sensible.  Take a look at your subquery again.

```sql
SELECT content 
  FROM tree /* << tree? */ 
 WHERE MATCH(node.content) /* << node? */ ...
```

Your table here is `tree`. Specifying a match against a column in `node` applies no sensible selection criteria to `tree` but is going to match every row in tree, just as if you had said `WHERE 1` or `WHERE 1 = 1` or `WHERE 2+2 != 5`, or no rows in `tree`, as would `WHERE 1 = 0`.  The server returns all rows, `LIMIT 1,` and if that 1 row doesn't provide the correct 'content,' then the outer query returns no rows... or the subquery returns no rows because the `WHERE` is imposssible to satisfy.  It's not clear, which, without further analysis, but as written, the query does not seem to do what you intend.

I believe you intended this:

```
 WHERE MATCH(tree.content) AGAINST ...
```

I admit I am not fully convinced of the validity of the approach, as a solution to what you're really trying to accomplish, but this seems like a logical error that would explan "no results."

You might also find value in my answer to [MYSQL matching one column to another in a different table via a FULLTEXT index](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/44986/11651) on dba.SE, the Stack Exchange site for database administrators.  Of course, by "a different table," the question actually referred to a join, so that solution is also useful for joining a table to itself.  The solution uses a stored function to relieve the restriction against referencing a column in `AGAINST()`, which you don't need, but it also handles the `LIMIT 1` so that you get a scalar value.

However... it seems like if you want multiple rows, a scalar subquery or a stored function isn't right, either.  You need a derived table, which MySQL calls a [subquery in the `FROM` clause](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/from-clause-subqueries.html).  Support for `LIMIT` in derived tables varies by server version, IIRC.